# urls.py в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Всем привет. Только начал ковырять Django и уже застопорился.

Организация директорий следующая:

```
Testproject
- manage.py
- blog
--urls.py
--views.py
--...
-testproject
--urls.py
--...
```

Содержимое /blog/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

Содержимое /blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Содержимое /testproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', include(blog.urls))
]
```

Ругается на то, что

```
File "~/testproject/testproject/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('test/', include(blog.urls))
NameError: name 'blog' is not defined
```

Вроде все делал по гайдам. В чем проблема, почему Include меня не понимает?

Answer (score 1):

тупейшая ошибка, нужно было обличить 'blog.urls' в кавычки. Не актуально.